# JQUERY Plugin, slide between tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, slide

I would like to slide right or left between my tabs in (`<ul> <li> </li> <li> </li> </ul>`)
each 'li' TAG represents one tab.

I have found this one http://www.fruitbatscode.com/demos/simplecarousel/,

[image]

For some reason it didn't work in the web site on my server. I spent one day trying to locate the problem but I was unable to solve it.

Just wanted to know if there are any other JS or jQuery  plugins similar to the 'carousel' jQuery plugin?

Comment: Can you post link to your webpage or some code?

Comment: You probably have not done some of the basics, like including jQuery in your web page. Did you look at the source of the page and/or follow any instructions that come with the plugin?

Comment: How exactly isn't it working?

Comment: i'm giving up, now, just wanted to know if there any other js or jquery plugin similar to the 'carousel' jquery plugin